# How to use Google Cloud Secrets in Cloud Run using react?

Tags: reactjs, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, api-key

I'm developing a react website that uses some sensitive API keys.

I'm hosting the application on Google Cloud Run, via a container.

I would like to access API keys through Google Cloud Secret Manager, but I am not able to. When I try to access them, the return is "undefined".

Here is my code snippet:

```
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY)
```

And the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:1.19-alpine AS server
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder ./app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I'm deploying the application using the gcloud command:

```
gcloud run deploy test-gcr-react \
--image gcr.io/test-gcr-react-app/test-gcr-react \
--region=southamerica-east1 \
--set-secrets=REACT_APP_API_KEY=REACT_APP_API_KEY:latest \
--allow-unauthenticated
```

PS: I have already given the proper access permissions to the service account "Default compute service account" to be a "Secret Manager Secret Acessor" of the secret `REACT_APP_API_KEY`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common issue. Think about the role and the behavior of each layer:

- NGINX serve directly the react JS
- The react JS is ran directly on the user browser.

therefore, NEVER, the env var (your secret) is read. NGINX doesn't care of it, the user browser can't access Cloud Run env var.

---

The trick here is to set the API KEY in a conf file of your react APP at build time (in your dockerfile). The secret must be in the JS before the runtime. NGINX only serve JS, not update/change it

Comment: Your comment makes sense, he is running nginx to serve static content, which won't read env vars once react is built.

If you are using find-replace during build that's also a problem. I strongly recommend you use nodejs and host your react code in hosted mode or at least read these values from a backend not directly from frontend.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, tanks for your reply! I understood the problem, but if I use a conf file for the KEYS, they will be visible on browser and this is not secure, right?

Comment: That's right @GoatSolutions, you may want to wrap it in the backend or make sure to render these values on the backend.

Comment: Either you wrap it in your backend. But sometimes, with Google Cloud Maps for instance, you can embed it in your backend. You have to restrict your API key usage https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean `Secret Manager Secret Accessor` role.

In order to do so you can do this:

```bash
gcloud secrets add-iam-policy-binding secret-id \
--member="serviceAccount:<project-number>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" \
--role="roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"
```

But, make sure your cloud run is **really using that service account**, if not change the `member` field in the command up above to **correct it to the appropriate service account** instead.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks Ernani. I will fix the post.